# How do I pass data from a thread using wxThreadEvent?

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I have a GUI and a worker thread, and I want to send data from the worker to the GUI. I'm using QueueEvent and wxThreadEvents to preserve model-view separation. I'm getting a baadf00d error somehow.

```
const int EvtID = 42;

MyFrame::MyFrame()
{
  ...
  // this seems to work correctly,
  //   but I'm including it in case it is part of the problem
  Bind(wxEVT_THREAD, (wxObjectEventFunction)&MyFrame::OutputData, this, EvtID);
  ...
}

MyFrame::OutputData(wxThreadEvent* event)
{
  // should get data from MyThread,
  //   but outputs 0xBA, 0xAD, 0xF0, 0x0D in successive calls
  output << event->GetInt();
}

MyThread::CreateOutputWithLocal()
{
  wxThreadEvent event(wxEVT_THREAD, EvtID);
  event.SetInt(getData());
  //pFrame is a wxEvtHandler*
  pFrame->QueueEvent(event.Clone());
}

MyThread::CreateOutputWithPointer()
{
  wxThreadEvent* event = new wxThreadEvent(wxEVT_THREAD, EvtID);
  event->SetInt(getData());
  //pFrame is a wxEvtHandler*
  pFrame->QueueEvent(event); // QueueEvent() takes control of the pointer and deletes it
}
```

Using `wxThreadEvent`'s `SetPayload()` and `GetPayload()` or its `SetExtraLong()` and `GetExtraLong()` doesn't seem to make any difference. What do I need to get this to work?

Comment: This doesn't look like the real code (missing function return types &c), so the problem is probably in the part that you don't show us because there doesn't seem to be anything wrong here. Well, you should remove the cast from `Bind()` argument as it's unnecessary and potentially harmful, but otherwise I don't see anything.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the problem turned out to be in another part of the code. This part was accurately transferring the data, but the part that was getting data was messed up.

Comment: Ah, `Bind()` doesn't require a certain type of function pointer, unlike `Connect()`, which is what the form generator used and what I copied from. So my call should be `Bind(wxEVT_THREAD, &MyFrame::OutputData, this, EvtID);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set/GetPayload should do the trick. May be you are doing it wrongly. Your code will be of more help. But here is a stripped example showing the usage of the Two methods.

```
Connect(wxID_ANY, wxEVT_COMMAND_DATA_SENT, wxThreadEventHandler(GMainFrame::OnAddText), NULL, this);//connect event to a method

void* MyThread::Entry(){
    wxThreadEvent e(wxEVT_COMMAND_DATA_SENT);//declared and implemented somewhere
    wxString text("I am sent!");
    e.SetPayload(wxString::Format("%s", text.c_str()));
    theParent->GetEventHandler()->AddPendingEvent(e);
    return NULL;
}


void GMainFrame::OnAddText(wxThreadEvent& event) {
    wxString t = event.GetPayload<wxString>();
    wxMessageBox(t);
}
```

A stripped version from a sample I wrote long ago when playing around wxThreadEvent

Comment: Thanks. There's not much in the way of code examples for wxThreadEvent handling that I could find online, so seeing how it should be set up is definitely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would just store the pay load in a thread safe queue that would belong to the frame.

Before you queue the event, queue the data in the thread safe queue. In the OutputData function, flush the queue and read the data that is in it.

I'm using this strategy to pass `boost::function < void () >` to the UI, so it's very scallable, because I can trigger almost anything from the engine thread.

Comment: That works too, but `EvtHandler::QueueEvent()` is already a thread-safe method for passing data to the UI, and `wxThreadEvent`'s `GetPayload<T>()` and `SetPayload<T>()` are templated, so they'll take any type of data. I didn't want to include the boost library when I already had what I needed in the libraries I was using.

Comment: Ah, yeah, ok. I forgot to do that. :)